# What is “Personal data” in MINOS terminals in Beyond a Steel Sky?

Tags: beyond-a-steel-sky

When you enter this directory in the MINOS terminals, it show the title “Your photo archive”. Below it, there are 24 empty squares. It also says “Files found: 0”. I completed the game and didn’t see anything added here. I thought it may be for developer commentary, but I restarted the game with commentaries on and this “Photo Archive” is still empty.

Is it a non-completed feature?

<sub>***Note**: I play the Apple Arcade version on [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) if that makes a difference.*</sub>